# UICollection view cell flip effect

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am making the collection view cell to flip and provide the information about the cell.

StoryBoard:

```
-Collectionviewcell
-- View1 (tag 100)
-- View2 (tag 200)
```

code on **didSelectItemAtIndexPath**.

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *firstView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
UIView *secondView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
NSString *indexValue = [flipIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (![indexValue isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        NSLog(@"ANIMATION STARTED");
        [UIView transitionFromView:secondView
                            toView:firstView
                          duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                              [firstView setHidden:NO];
                              [secondView setHidden:YES];
                          }];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"ANIMATION COMPLETED");
    }];

    [flipIndex removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [flipIndex insertObject:@"1" atIndex:indexPath.row];
} else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        NSLog(@"ANIMATION STARTED");
        [UIView transitionFromView:firstView
                            toView:secondView
                          duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                              [secondView setHidden:NO];
                              [firstView setHidden:YES];
                          }];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"ANIMATION COMPLETED");
    }];
```

The issue I am facing here is that on first click the view flips from view1 to view 2. On second tap on the view2 the view1 is blank because it is nil.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:cell.contentView
    duration:1
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
    animations:^{
    if (cell.isFirstView) {
        cell.isFirstView = NO;

        firstView.hidden = NO;
        secondView.hidden=YES;
    } else {
        cell.isFirstView = YES;

        firstView.hidden = YES;
        secondView.hidden = NO;
    }
} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass UICollectionViewCell with two UIView outlet properties, then hook them up in storyboard.

```
customCell.view1
customCell.view2
```

They could then be accessed without relying on tags and neither will be nil, then instead of relying on flipIndex (which is what I think you are doing?) to determine which is showing you could:

```
if (customCell.view1.hidden) {
      //flip to 1
} else {
      //flip to 2
}
```

Remember to reset the views when reusing them however.